# How to efficiently store and merge variables in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, memory, merge

I have 600 `.txt` files (in total about 250GB). For each file I compute an additional variable which I would need to merge with another separate (smaller) dataset. I do need all observations in all 600 `txt` files to compute these variables.

Currently I calculate this variable for each file separately (merging all 600 files is impossible), and save only this variable with the unique ID in a separate `txt` file.

The problem is that I keep running out of memory. Is there a more efficient way to merge this? Any suggestions are very welcome.

My code is the following (it works perfectly when applied on 1 small file):
I do the following for each of the 600 files:
1. compute extra variables,
2. subset dataset containing only the variable I need and a unique ID to merge,
3. save as `txt` file.

```
files <- list.files("path", pattern = "*.TXT")

# Loop over files
for (i in 1:length(files))
{
  data <- read.table(files[i], header = TRUE)

  # Compute extra variables
  data$newvar <- (data$v1 * data$v2)
  data <- ddply(data, .(v3,v4,v5), transform, newvar2 = sum(newvar)) 

  # Subset data
  varstokeep <- c("ID", "newvar2")
  data <- data[varstokeep]

  # Save data
  write.table(data, paste("path[", i, "].txt"), sep = "\t")

  rm(data)
}
```

Comment: First, I think you should overhaul your entire workflow in R to the data.table way of doing everything: from reading in data (use `fread` instead) to calculating new variables (use assignment by reference `:=` or `set`. data.table is meant just for the problem you have: Big data in R. If you still have memory problems, then you might have to set up a database and do things from there or, look into `ffdf`

Comment: Also,what is the size of the largest text file?, and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: The largest file is about 2GB. My desktop has 8GB RAM. I also have access to a server of 128GB RAM, but even there it seems to take hours just for the first file only. I use the same code where i keep a substantially more limited number of observations and that is done in a few hours only, so I guess it is the writing to txt files that consumes that much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Load libs data.table         
library(data.table)

#File list
files <- list.files("path", pattern = "*.TXT")

#Define variables to keep
varstokeep <- c("ID", "newvar2")

# Loop over files
for (i in 1:length(files)){

  #Use fread here : very fast, reads straight into a data.table
  data <- fread(files[i], header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

  # Compute extra variables, see `?":="`
  data[, newvar:=v1*v2]

  # Sum of all values on "newvar" per shop(v3), per category (v4), per week
data[, newvar2:=sum(newvar), .(v3, v4, v5)] 

  # index of variables not to keep
  vartodrop <- which(!names(data)%in%varstokeep)

  # Subset data: again, efficiently with ":="
  set(data, i=NULL, j=vartodrop, value=NULL)

  # Save data
  write.table(data, paste("path[", i, "].txt"), sep = "\t")

  rm(data)
}
```

In this solution, no unnecessary copies of your data are made. This removes any overheads from using `data.frames` which are copied over during each modification, potentially, demanding more memory than you have. Note the scarcity of `<-` 's. See if this is enough to solve your mem issues.

Comment: thanks a lot! i adapted everything. I also merge each file with another file in the process (left out above for simplicity) using data <- merge(data, data2, by.x="ID", all.x=TRUE) but now i get an error "Error in merge.data.table: by.x and by.y must be of the same length. Would I have to change the merging code as well (it worked before).

Comment: "data <- ddply(data, .(v3,v4,v5), transform, newvar2 = sum(newvar))" adds a new variable to the data (newvar2), which is the sum of another variable ("newvar"), by each unique combination of v3, v4 and v5. In other words, I have panel data and would like the sum of all values on "newvar" per shop(v3), per category (v4), per week(v5).

Comment: If the merge columns have the same names in `data` and in `data2`, then do `data <- merge(data, data2, by="ID", all.x=TRUE)`. If they have different names, you must specify `by.x` and `by.y`

Comment: thanks again.. I just have 1 error left: "Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'ID' is a factor column being joined to i.'ID' which is type 'double'. Factor columns must join to factor or character columns."

Comment: @research111 See edit, be sure to go through the data.table documentation and vignettes to understand whats happening up there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into detail at data.table as I'll need it a lot more, but this at least get's me started. thanks

Comment: @research111 See edit, there was a missing `!` which would drop the variables you want to keep and keep the ones you want to drop: its fixed now. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think @Shekeine is right that you need to re-think your approach to your data, but for now a quick and dirty solution might be to force a garbage collection with `gc()` after you've removed the current iteration of `data` from your environment.

```
...
  # Save data
  write.table(data, paste("path[", i, "].txt"), sep = "\t")

  rm(data)
  gc()
}
```

NB: R usually clears up after itself anyway, but this might just be enough to process your files. Consider this a hack; this is not something to rely on!